# Circle Detection

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, detection, geometry

I need help developing a circle detection algorithm to detect snooker balls. Does anyone know any algorithms that can be implemented in C and open cv? I'm having trouble getting this done

Comment: more detail, do you know the color of the snooker balls? The background? Is this a webcam feed or a picture made in photoshop?

Comment: well i have to detect the 22 snooker balls and then i will have to determine the different colours but i want to take one step at a time. so for now all i need is to detect 22 circles(snooker balls). is ther some hough transform in opencv i could use or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple object detection using OpenCV and machine learning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416117/simple-object-detection-using-opencv-and-machine-learning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV 2.3 comes with [HoughCircles](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cvhoughlines2#houghcircles). The C++ API for OpenCV 2.1 also implements the function: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_feature_detection.html#HoughCircles

Comment: cheers. this will help a lot. i might aswell ask while im here if anyone knows how to detect the colours of these circles once there detected?

Comment: @user966890: This blog post might help: http://www.lirtex.com/robotics/fast-object-tracking-robot-computer-vision/

Comment: @user966890: See also the paper [Real-time color ball tracking for augmented reality](http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/sykorad/Sykora08-EGVE.pdf) and demonstration video on YouTube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-NaRj8Rznw