# Analyze image and find dots in iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing

I am looking for a solution to identify dots in an image in iOS. The idea is to pick an image with the UIImagePicker. Then, analyze the image for dots of a certain size range and give as output the number of dots found.

I heard about openCV. Does anyone has an example of this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I come accross [this](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/) link recently which is OpenCV for iOS you can use this as a starting point. Also take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404062/opencv-dot-target-detection-not-finding-all-targets-and-found-circles-are-offse) for spots detection.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll explore them and let you know. I didn't know there was a iOS OpenCV.

Comment: You are welcome! as i guess you are new to the site please take a look to the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq and validate my answer if u feel this is correct.