# Detect clusters of circular objects by iterative adaptive thresholding and shape analysis

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, opencv, openmp

I have been developing an application to count circular objects such as bacterial colonies from pictures.

What make it easy is the fact that the objects are generally well distinct from the background.

However, few difficulties make the analysis tricky:

1. The background will present gradual as well as rapid intensity change.
2. In the edges of the container, the object will be elliptic rather than circular.
3. The edges of the objects are sometimes rather fuzzy.
4. The objects will cluster.
5. The object can be very small (6px of diameter)
6. Ultimately, the algorithms will be used (via GUI) by people that do not have deep understanding of image analysis, so the parameters must be intuitive and very few.

The problem has been address many times in the scientific literature and "solved", for instance, using circular Hough transform or watershed approaches, but I have never been satisfied by the results.

One simple approach that was described is to get the foreground by adaptive thresholding and split (as I described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313602/reshaping-noisy-coin-into-a-circle-form/10324759#10324759)) the clustered objects using distance transform.

I have successfully implemented this method, but it could not always deal with sudden change in intensity. Also, I have been asked by peers to come out with a more "novel" approach.

**I therefore was looking for a new method to extract foreground.**

I therefore investigated other thresholding/blob detection methods.
I tried MSERs but found out that they were not very robust and quite slow in my case.

I eventually came out with an algorithm that, so far, gives me excellent results:

1. I split the three channels of my image and reduce their noise (blur/median blur). For each channel:
2. I apply a manual implementation of the first step of adaptive thresholding by calculating the absolute difference between the original channel and a convolved (by a large kernel blur) one. Then, for all the relevant values of threshold:
3. I apply a threshold on the result of 2)
4. find contours
5. validate or invalidate contours on the grant of their shape (size, area, convexity...)
6. only the valid continuous regions (*i.e.* delimited by contours) are then redrawn in an accumulator (1 accumulator per channel).
7. After accumulating continuous regions over values of threshold, I end-up with a map of "scores of regions". The regions with the highest intensity being those that fulfilled the the morphology filter criteria the most often.
8. The three maps (one per channel) are then converted to grey-scale and thresholded (the threshold is controlled by the user)

Just to show you the kind of image I have to work with: 
[image]
This picture represents part of 3 sample images in the top and the result of my algorithm (blue = foreground) of the respective parts in the bottom.

Here is my C++ implementation of : 3-7

```
/*
 * cv::Mat dst[3] is the result of the absolute difference between original and convolved channel.
 * MCF(std::vector<cv::Point>, int, int) is a filter function that returns an positive int only if the input contour is valid.
 */

/* Allocate 3 matrices (1 per channel)*/
cv::Mat accu[3];

/* We define the maximal threshold to be tried as half of the absolute maximal value in each channel*/
int maxBGR[3];
for(unsigned int i=0; i<3;i++){
    double min, max;
    cv::minMaxLoc(dst[i],&min,&max);
    maxBGR[i] = max/2;
    /* In addition, we fill accumulators by zeros*/
    accu[i]=cv::Mat(compos[0].rows,compos[0].cols,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));
}
/* This loops are intended to be multithreaded using
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic)
For each channel */
for(unsigned int i=0; i<3;i++){
    /* For each value of threshold (m_step can be > 1 in order to save time)*/
    for(int j=0;j<maxBGR[i] ;j += m_step ){
            /* Temporary matrix*/
            cv::Mat tmp;
            std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
            /* Thresholds dst by j*/
            cv::threshold(dst[i],tmp, j, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
            /* Finds continous regions*/
            cv::findContours(tmp, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1);
            if(contours.size() > 0){
                /* Tests each contours*/
                for(unsigned int k=0;k<contours.size();k++){
                    int valid = MCF(contours[k],m_minRad,m_maxRad);
                    if(valid>0){
                        /* I found that redrawing was very much faster if the given contour was copied in a smaller container.
                         * I do not really understand why though. For instance,
                         cv::drawContours(miniTmp,contours,k,cv::Scalar(1),-1,8,cv::noArray(), INT_MAX, cv::Point(-rect.x,-rect.y));
                         is slower especially if contours is very long.
                         */
                        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > tpv(1);
                        std::copy(contours.begin()+k, contours.begin()+k+1, tpv.begin());
                        /* We make a Roi here*/
                        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(tpv[0]);
                        cv::Mat miniTmp(rect.height,rect.width,CV_8U,cv::Scalar(0));
                        cv::drawContours(miniTmp,tpv,0,cv::Scalar(1),-1,8,cv::noArray(), INT_MAX, cv::Point(-rect.x,-rect.y));
                        accu[i](rect)    = miniTmp + accu[i](rect);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
/* Make the global scoreMap*/
cv::merge(accu,3,scoreMap);
/* Conditional noise removal*/
if(m_minRad>2)
    cv::medianBlur(scoreMap,scoreMap,3);
cvtColor(scoreMap,scoreMap,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the name of such foreground extraction approach and do you see any reason for which it could be improper to use it in this case ?
2. Since recursively finding and drawing contours is quite intensive, I would like to make my algorithm faster. Can you indicate me any way to achieve this goal ?

Thank you very much for you help,

Comment: Did you try [Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) instead of steps 2 and 3? It's an extremely fast adaptive threshold that can easily be computed from the  histogram. It usually works quite well for background suppression. Syntax is e.g. `cvThreshold(img_src, img_dest, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU); `.

Comment: @smocking Thank you very much, I did, but 1) I found it does not work as well as adaptive threshold for all my samples. And 2), step 2 and 3 produce are relatively fast (compared to 3-7) to produce the grey-scale image needed latter on...

Comment: OK sounds good; what about using [connected component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling) to find the contiguous shapes? Unfortunately it's not in the base OpenCV library, but there's a library called [cvBlobsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib/) that will do it.

Comment: @smocking Thank you, as far as I am aware,  cv::findContours() is actually explicitly finding connected components. In addition, I need this components as contours at some point since I am filtering them according to some morphological features (via my function "MCF"). So I did not expect improvements by replacing cv::findContours by a custom connected components labelling function.

Answer (score 2):

Several years ago I wrote an aplication that detects cells in a microscope image. The code is written in Matlab, and I think now that is more complicated than it should be (it was my first CV project), so I will only outline tricks that will actually be helpful for you. Btw, it was deadly slow, but it was really good at separating large groups of twin cells.

I defined a metric by which to evaluate the chance that a given point is the center of a cell:
 - Luminosity decreases in a circular pattern around it
 - The variance of the texture luminosity follows a given pattern
 - a cell will not cover more than % of a neighboring cell

With it, I started to iteratively find the best cell, mark it as found, then look for the next one. Because such a search is expensive, I employed genetic algorithms to search faster in my feature space.

Some results are given below:

[image: Cells 2]
[image: Cells]

Comment: Thank you, I like the approach you used for your project!. Can you post the originals of the pictures you have put ? In my case, I do not think I can go as deep since I do not want to make extra assumptions about luminosity pattern or texture (some object being darker in the edges for instance). I aim to find a versatile solution and, as I said in my post, I am also concerned about processing speed.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was overly complicated, but the results were great. I think a simpler solution will give you good results - like morphology, combined with adaptive thresholding. I will post the pics, and maybe some more info later, when I get home.