# python separate round particles by offsetting contours / shrinking polygones

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

I'm new to python and stuck..

I want to make a python script that allows me to separate adjacent particles on an image like this:

[image: BEFORE]

into separate regions like this:

[image: AFTER]

I was suggested to use the watershed method, which as far as I understand it would give me a something like this:

[image: Watershed in 3D]

**EDIT** *Actually found out that this is distance transform and not watershed*

Where I then could use a threshold to separate them.. Followed this [openCV watershed guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294859/how-to-define-the-markers-for-watershed-in-opencv/11438165#11438165) but it only worked to cut out the particles. Was not able to "transform" the code to do what I want.

I then took another approach. Tried to use the [openCV contours](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/2012/06/hi-this-article-is-tutorial-which-try.html) which gave me good contours of the particles. I have then been looking intensively for an easy way to perform polygon offset in order to shrink the edge like this:

[image: Edge offset]

Using the center from the offset contours (polygon) should give me the number of particles.. But I just haven been able to find a simple way to do edge offset / polygon shrinking with python.

Comment: You might be interested by : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313602/reshaping-noisy-coin-into-a-circle-form/10324759#10324759
Distance transform might be useful in your case. As far as I understand it, polygon shrinking could be equivalent to thresholding the distanceMap, no ?

Comment: +1 for Quentin link, distanceTransform is what you are looking for and the example is very similar to your problem

Comment: The distance transform acutually got me very far, but then @Nicolas Barbey posted a really nice and easy solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a script using numpy, scipy and the scikit-image (aka skimage). It makes use of local maxima extraction and watershading plus labeling (ie connected components extraction).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage
import skimage.feature
import skimage.morphology

# parameters
THRESHOLD = 128

# read image
im = scipy.misc.imread("JPh65.png")
# convert to gray image
im = im.mean(axis=-1)
# find peaks
peak = skimage.feature.peak_local_max(im, threshold_rel=0.9, min_distance=10)
# make an image with peaks at 1
peak_im = np.zeros_like(im)
for p in peak:
    peak_im[p[0], p[1]] = 1
# label peaks
peak_label, _ = scipy.ndimage.label(peak_im)
# propagate peak labels with watershed
labels = skimage.morphology.watershed(255 - im, peak_label)
# limit watershed labels to area where the image is intense enough
result = labels * (im > THRESHOLD)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - would you mind telling me what scipy.ndimage.label does and how the peak_label is used in watershed?

Comment: scipy.ndimage.label performs connected component labeling (it assigns a number to a cluster of 1 pixels surounded by zeros). peak_label is used to set seeds for the watershed (afaik regions are grown from seeds by the watershed algorithm).

Comment: Thank you once again @Nicolas for clearing that out. -just a silly question: is it possible to label with random numbers (seems like it is incrementing)?

Comment: You can change label number afterwards doing something like result[result == 3] = 5 for instance. Looping through label indexes and np.random.rand will give you a random number.

Comment: If you feel my answer is useful and working for you, don't hesitate to vote for it ;)

Comment: Checked your answer as the solution.. I just forgot to vote - sorry about that