# Android application for reading money

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to make an Android Application that captures an image and searches it for coins and paper notes and then determines the value of the money in the image.

Additionally, the output of the system will be such that it can be understood by a blind person.

- What functions and techniques in openCV would suit these tasks?
- What limitations and development hurdles can I expect?

Comment: Does the blind person take the picture?

Comment: You could use the size of the coin, if there is a reference size somewhere

Comment: Pls state what you have already tried. We probably can help you more then! SOreadytohelp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coin Recognition on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456366/coin-recognition-on-android)

Comment: The blind person takes the image for the money then the application should tell him what is the value of the money (Money reader application).

Comment: @Anonymous You should explain that Blind Person SCANs the Currency note. Not Capture the note :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to program android apps,you need to do the following:-

1. Download the OpenCV SDK and set it up with the IDE.
2. Recognising shapes will be a huge part of your project, see the contour detection example that is present with the SDK examples. Your primary goal will be detecting a circle. Later you need to adapt your algorithm according to the currency. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJNazQu7yH0) will be of particular interest to you.
3. Learn the different image processing techniques like thresholding for better accurate results. Understanding what a Mat object is and how it can be manipulated is important.
4. Finally improve the accuracy of your algorithm, as sometimes lighting conditions make the difference between a good review and a dissatisfied user.

Comment: Thanks ,,,, you mean I need to focus on how to improve the quality of image in order to finding the centroid & Diameter which yield to calculate the area of the coin then I can recognize the coin value by comparing the area value with known values.

Comment: Something like that, but you don't need the centroid, use contour detection.

Comment: This is about coins ... BUT what if the money are papers not coins and all have the same dimensions but different values .... this technique cannot be applied in this case !!!!

Comment: It will be applicable for paper money as well. Only difference now your search for contours is on a rectangular object. Easy peasy.

Comment: BUT if papers all have the same dimensions but different values then you can't differentiate between their values using this technique since all have the same area !!! I need another technique that will be applicable for this case.

Comment: Now here's where you are wrong, all currency bills are not the same size. Secondly finding a rectangle is all you want to do. After that just call the  contours function within the rectangle bounds! I suggest you to actually start working a sample project to get an idea as to what you are doing!

Comment: Look for Vuforia SDK for Android. It can do what you need but I think it cost money if you need a dataSet (images) bigger than 100.