# OpenCV: Error in cvHoughCircles usage

Tags: c, .net, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I am using cvHoughCircles to find the two white ovals in the following image:

[image]

I first used thresholding for locating the white regions and then used Hough Transforms. But the output is not coming correct as shown below:

[image]

I am not able to understand what is happening?  Why it is detecting 3 circles and why only one is being detected correctly? Any suggestions?

Below is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<malloc.h>



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( ) {
IplImage* image = cvLoadImage( 
"testing.bmp",
  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE
);

IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("testing.bmp");
CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);


cvThreshold( src, src,  200, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

CvSeq* results = cvHoughCircles( 
image, 
 storage, 
 CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
 3, 
 image->width/10 
 ); 

 for( int i = 0; i < results->total; i++ ) 
 {
 float* p = (float*) cvGetSeqElem( results, i );
 CvPoint pt = cvPoint( cvRound( p[0] ), cvRound( p[1] ) );
 cvCircle( 
  src,
  pt, 
  cvRound( p[2] ),
  CV_RGB(0xff,0,0) 
);
}
cvNamedWindow( "HoughCircles", 1 );
cvShowImage( "HoughCircles", src);
cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

Edit:

Since I am not get satisfactory results with Hough Transform, I am willing to go for some other way. I can assume that each white blob in the figure is of equal size (size is known)and also the distance between the blob is known. Is there a non-trivial way I can find a vertical line (a tangent) touching the left side of left white blob? Once I know this tangent, I get an idea of the boundary location, then I will draw a circle at x=(this location + radius(which is known)), y= this location.  Can I find such x and y coordinates using some non-trivial ways?

**Solved, by changing as per below:**

```
cvThreshold(image, image,  220, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

cvCanny(image, image, 255, 255, 3);


cvNamedWindow( "edge", 1 );
cvShowImage( "edge", image);
cvWaitKey(0);

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* results = cvHoughCircles( 
             image, 
             storage, 
             CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
             4, 
             image->width/4, 100,100,0,50);
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps I am not familiar with OpenCv, but shouldn't you use the edge image, not the thresholded as input to Hough algorithm?

Comment: using Canny edge detection, followed by Hough Transformed worked! But when I take another image with more no. of white blobs, the same algo failed.

Comment: @Andrey, do you think for Oval shape detection the same procedure should be used? (Because in my case actually the shapes are oval and not circular)

Comment: Actually edges are detected perfectly when the thresholding is done before canny. But I guess internally Canny would involve thresholding also. So there might be some issues in parameters. Anyway your answer worked for me for some other images as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use edge detected image as input, not the thresholded.
Secondly, Hough circles will not work for elipses, unless they are very close to circles. I recommend reading about [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform) and implementing it for ellipses.

Comment: Thershoding should be done , and then edge and then hough Transforms. In my case for images with nearly circular shape the solutions worked , but oval shaped did not. So I guess Genralised Hough Transform may be a better solution. The application in hand is actually much simpler     as I know size and many other parameter of the white blobs, so may be some trivial method also work in my case.

Answer (score 3):

[It's all about](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417109/176769) [the parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500949/176769):

```
IplImage* src = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
if (!src)
{
    cout << "Failed: unable to load image " << argv[1] << endl;
    return -1;
}

//IplImage* image = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
IplImage* image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(src->width, src->height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvCvtColor(src, image, CV_RGB2GRAY);

cvThreshold(image, image,  220, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
//  cvNamedWindow( "thres", 1 );
//  cvShowImage( "thres", image);
//  cvWaitKey(0);

CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* results = cvHoughCircles( 
                 image, 
                 storage, 
                 CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                 4, 
                 image->width/3); 

std::cout << "> " << results->total << std::endl;

for( int i = 0; i < results->total; i++ ) 
{
    float* p = (float*) cvGetSeqElem( results, i );
    CvPoint pt = cvPoint( cvRound( p[0] ), cvRound( p[1] ) );
    cvCircle(src,
             pt, 
             cvRound( p[2] ),
             CV_RGB(0xff,0,0));
}

cvNamedWindow( "HoughCircles", 1 );
cvShowImage( "HoughCircles", src);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

If you've done a little bit more experimentation you would have eventually found out that [with different parameters you get different results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416361/176769):

[image]

Comment: Tried my best , used your's as well as these parameters:  CvSeq* results = cvHoughCircles( 
                 image, 
                 storage, 
                 CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,1 );  But did not work, no circle being detected, return >0

Comment: The code above produced the image I shared. I used OpenCV 2.3.1. I suggest you test this in another machine.

Comment: I am having libraries like opencv_core240.lib, so it means I am having opencv 2.4. Your values 4, image->width/3 corresponds to "dp = 1: The inverse ratio of resolution" and "Minimum distance between detected centers" Am I right?

Comment: I don't know by heart but you can find it out by looking at OpenCV 2.3 documentation. By the way, I just tested my code on a Windows box with OpenCV 2.3.1 and it also worked.