# Python cv2 edge and contour detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect bubbles on an OMR sheet which looks something like this:

[image: Raw image]

My code for edge detection and contour display is referenced from [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/). However, before finding the actual contours, I am trying to detect the edges but somehow not able to set the correct values of parameters.
This is what I get:

[image: edged]

Code:

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.50):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)


# return the edged image
return edged

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

r = 500.0 / image.shape[1]
dim = (500, int(image.shape[0] * r))

# perform the actual resizing of the image and show it
image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
equalized_img =  cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
cv2.imshow('Equalized', equalized_img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(equalized_img, (7, 7), 0)
# edged =cv2.Canny(equalized_img, 30, 160)
edged = auto_canny(blurred)

cv2.imshow('edged', edged)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

How can I get all the 90*4 circles?

Comment: you can extrapolate the direction and distance between circles from the detected ones, so you can get the coordinates of the missing ones.

Comment: Have you tried Otsu binarization?

Comment: hi Akhilesh, any of the answers below was of any help? Sorry to resume it late.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Hough to search for circles. This method project every single white pixel as a circle, and tries to get as many overlapping pixels possible. You'll have to specify the predicted radiuses of circles to be found within image.

[image: Hough projects every white pixel on circles within specified radi]

- Left - original image
- Top-right - each white pixel is projected as red circle - they are too small to find intersecting point
- Bottom-right - green circle is larger, and all the intersecting points meet exactly at the middle of the circle! Both radius and position is returned by `cvHoughCircles`

This person dealt with blob detection (that's what finding circles is called I think) using `cvHoughCircles` with `cvCanny`-ized image (read OPs update).

[OpenCV: Error in cvHoughCircles usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653433/opencv-error-in-cvhoughcircles-usage)

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your contour detection. 
Eventually by not changing it, but by better pre-processing the earlier stage.
Contour detection works better with more contrast and color separation in image. If you don´t have yet need to threshold you image with techniques like Simple Threshold, Adaptive or more smart techniques like Otsu's. Check Open CV document [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).

Besides that, for your case eventually need more advanced techniques like "Adaptive Thresholding Using the Integral Image", described [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.420.7883&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable.  Please provide context in your answer so that it's self-contained.